# How to make a function use CASE and IFNULL in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, case, ifnull

can you tell me how to use CASE and IFNULL in postgre? i'm migrating from sql to postgreSQL, and i want to make a function with this syntax :

```
SELECT a.furniture_id, a.furniture_brand, a.furniture_cost, 
CASE 
  WHEN furniture_id = f_id THEN a.furniture_content 
  ELSE '' 
END CONTENT 
   FROM tb_furniture a
   WHERE 
    (IFNULL(a.sale_id,0) = IFNULL(f_id,0) OR (a.furniture_id = f_Id AND IFNULL(a.furniture_content,'') > '')) 
    AND a.published = 1;
```

thanks before(y)

Comment: Er, PostgreSQL is SQL. Do you mean "I'm migrating from Microsoft SQL Server to PostgreSQL"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be what you are after, but carefully check the `WHERE` conditions:

```
SELECT a.furniture_id, a.furniture_brand, a.furniture_cost, 
       CASE WHEN a.furniture_id = f_id
       THEN a.furniture_content 
       ELSE '' 
       END AS content
FROM tb_furniture a
WHERE (coalesce(a.sale_id,0) = coalesce(f_id,0) OR length(content) > 0)
  AND a.published = 1;
```

Comment: I don't think there is an `IFNULL` in PostgreSQL, you'd want to use the standard [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) or skip the conversion and go to [`IS DISTINCT FROM` or `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html).

Comment: Yeah. Obvious mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @AnitaWulandari Since `f_id` is a parameter and used both in the `CASE` statement and in the `WHERE` condition, the latter can be simplified. See updated answer.